# $M$ subset of $L^2[0,1]$ that is closed and convex

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M = \{ f \in L^2[0,1]: f([0,1]) \subset [0,1] \hspace{2mm}a.e.\}$.
Show that $M$ is a closed and convex set.

My idea for it to be closed is similar to that of sequences, so I say:

Let $f \in \overline M$ and let's see what $f \in M$. Since $f \in \overline M$ there is a sequence $(f_k)^{\infty}_{k=1}$ such that $f_k \to f$, when $k \to \infty$, and every $f_k \in M$.

Now, we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $ \exists N(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $k> N \to \displaystyle\int^1_0 |f_k - f|^2 d\mu < \frac{\epsilon^2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Finally by triangular inequality and $\phi(t) = |t|^2$ is increasing
$$
\displaystyle\int^1_0 |f_k - f_l|^2 d\mu \le \displaystyle\int^1_0 |f_k - f^{(N)}_k|^2 d\mu + \displaystyle\int^1_0 |f^{(N)}_k - f^{(N)}_l|^2 d\mu + \displaystyle\int^1_0 |f^{(N)}_l - f_l|^2 d\mu < \epsilon^2
$$
Is my proof ok? also I do not know if convexity is inherited from what $\phi(t) = |t|^2$ is convex and increasing

Comment: I maybe don't follow what $f_k^{(N)}$ is.

Comment: sorry, you're right, but think of a matrix where $f^{(N)} = (f^{N}_1, f^{N}_2, f^{N}_3, ...) $ is the N-th row, and so on will converge to my new row $ f $

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your proof to do with the range of $f$, so I can't imagine that it can be a proof? The above just seems to be showing that the sequence is Cauchy. And no demonstration of convexity.

Comment: I understand you, the convexity is not clear to me, but I proved that $M$ is complete, so I understand that $f  \in M$ and as I take $f$ in the closure, it would be closed, right?

Comment: Well, convexity follows from more or less the definition. Showing that $M$ as a subspace is complete would be sufficient but you have not done that. You have just shown that the sequence is Cauchy which follows from convergence here.

Comment: Note that if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ there is a subsequence that converges everywhere.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I saw why it is convex, and for closed I need $f_n$ to have a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges to $f$ in [0,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N_f = \{ x | f(x) \notin [0,1] \}$. Suppose $f,g \in M$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then if $x \notin N_f \cup N_g$ we have
$\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda) g(x) \in [0,1]$. Hence $\lambda f+(1-\lambda) g \in M$.

Suppose $f_n \to f$ (in $L^2$), then there is a subsequence such that $f_{n_k}(x) \to f(x)$ for ae. $x$. Let $N$ be the corresponding null set.

Suppose $x \notin N \cup (\cup_n N_{f_n})$, then since $f_{n_k}(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $k$ we have $f(x) \in [0,1]$. Hence $f \in M$.